# PostgreSQL Audit History Using Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update

I have a requirement to maintain a History table that will track all the modifications that is happening in all the tables in my database.

The following is the approved sql, which is a generic table that will accept the table name, column name, values, the action involved (Insert/Update/Delete) etc.

```
CREATE TABLE "User_History" (
  "id" serial,
  "table_name" text NOT NULL,
  "column_name" text NOT NULL,
  "pk_id" text,
  "old_value" text,
  "new_value" text,
  "action" text,
  "modified_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  "modified_by" UUID NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Any CRUD operations across the database must be inserted into this table.

I have a total of 78 tables (which is probable to be increased in future).
The go to approach is the use of triggers. 
Which really worries me. Because, if my understanding is correct, I would have to create a function for each columns and then bind it to a trigger. Which means, if I have like a 10 columns each in 78 tables, then it will a total of 780 functions (each representing the individual columns of each tables) and an equal number of triggers that invokes these functions.

I really do hope there is a better solution for this. Keeping a track of this in code is not at all possible at the moment.

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but modified_at should be timestamptz to avoid differing results depending on the time zone of the user's session.  Also, it would be better to use regclass instead of text for table_name in case you get multiple tables with the same name in different schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You need one trigger *per table*, not per column.

You can either write a trigger function for each table, or write a generic one that works for all.